# How can I allow incoming calls to only vibrate when I have Do Not Disturb turned on?

Tags: calls, vibration, do-not-disturb

Currently, Do Not Disturb fully disables incoming calls, or only shows a silent notification. How can I just make it cause calls to vibrate when I have Do Not Disturb turned on?

**My real goal:**

I do deep-thinking work as a software developer. I need 4+ hr blocks of time undisturbed so I can do deep work. I'd like to start each work day by turning on "Do Not Disturb" mode for 8 hrs, but I need to still be notified of calls--just via vibrate is all so it's less-intrusive, in case it's a doctor's office, the [car repair person fixing my brakes](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/88265/71510), my wife with an important message, etc.

My phone is Google Pixel 5 with Android 12.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprompise: make phone calls less startling by having them vibrate, then slowly raise the ringer volume from 0% to 100% over ~5 seconds

Here is an alternative I just discovered which may meet my need: ie: do *not* turn "Do Not Disturb" on. Instead, do the following:

(the below was translated from French to English, since my phone is in French, so your wording may differ slightly--leave a comment)

**Settings --> Sound & vibration --> Vibration & haptics --> Vibrate for calls --> Vibrate, then progressive ring**

With this set, the phone vibrates a couple times when a call comes in, and then slowly raises the volume of the ringer up from 0 to 100% over like 5 seconds. This is *so* much more gentle and less distressing to my deep-thinking mind while I'm in the middle of something, and it gives me a chance to press a button to ignore the call before it gets loud, rather than startling me out of nowhere enough I lose my train of thought.

It's not quite what I was looking for, but this solution is an okay compromise for now.